# Count down from 60 seconds

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine, timespan

I was using this C# code in Unity3d to count up from zero seconds and display the result as well as increase a bar, but now I need it to count down from 60 seconds, I've replaced the values with 60, but it doesn't work, it actually counts down from 6 mins.

```
void UpdateTime()
{
    currentTime -= Time.deltaTime / 60f;

    barAmount = (int)Mathf.Lerp(0f, 100f, currentTime);

    timeBar.valueCurrent = barAmount;


    float cTime = 60f * currentTime;

    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cTime);

    timeTxt.text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",timeSpan.Days ,timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

    Debug.Log (timeTxt.text);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide us with code that we can run that replicates your issue?

Comment: It's not really possible to do that as I would have to provide the whole Unity project, but the above function, is what the problem is, for some reason it ends up being 6 mins, and I'm not sure why as I thought it was all in seconds.

Comment: It is true that it's impractical to provide an entire Unity3d project. On the other hand, it is also true that you do need to provide enough context for your problem to be comprehended. In many cases, questions that are nominally from a Unity3d context, can in fact be presented without any Unity3d aspect at all (i.e. they are actually not specific to Unity3d at all). In other cases, you still need to retain the Unity3d context, but can do so by providing complete details, such (e.g) what calls `UpdateTime()`, how often is it called, what does the expression `Time.deltaTime` represent, etc.

Comment: @Phil - It is really possible to do it. It's up to you how important getting an answer is. I suspect that the answer is quite simple, but I need to run your code to see the problem in action and to then be able to test a solution. The hardest thing in your code to replicate is `Mathf.Lerp`. You can probably do it in less than 10 minutes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String s;
public float currentTime = 60f;
private int barAmount;

void Update () {
   currentTime -= Time.deltaTime;
   barAmount = (int) Mathf.Lerp(0f, 100f, currentTime);
   // timeBar.valueCurrent = barAmount;
   float cTime = currentTime;
   TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cTime);

   s =  string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",timeSpan.Days ,timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
}
```

I just made a quick test and it works flawlessly. You don't need to divide through 60. `Time.deltaTime` is actually in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for that, barAmount though doensn't seem to change, it's stuck at 100 all the time when I do Debug.log(barAmount)

Comment: To answer my own comment, I just needed to change the bar amount line to barAmount = (int)Mathf.Lerp(0f, 100f, currentTime/60f);